# Zend Framework: Initializing Navigation in the Bootstrap

Tags: php, zend-framework, lazy-loading, zend-navigation

I currently initialize my web site navigation during bootstrap.  I initialize anywhere from 1 to 3 navigation objects.  Most requests will need the Navigation objects, but some don't.  The ones that don't include files generated for download and JSON requests.  I don't want to do the work of generating the navigation objects when they aren't going to be used.

I see two different possible solution types:

1. Specify routes that don't need the navigation, and check those during bootstrap
2. Lazy-load the navigation

For an acceptable solution I am looking for *specifics* in solving this problem.  I am interested in solution types that I haven't listed as well.

---

**SOLUTION**

I am accepting [FinalForm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/564791/finalform)'s answer, but it did not have the *specifics* that I was looking for.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Created one [lazy loading](http://www.virgentech.com/blog/2009/08/lazy-loading-resources-in-php.html) function in my `Navigation` database model class for each navigation object
2. Moved the corresponding Bootstrap code to each of the functions
3. Added an instance of my `Navigation` model to `Zend_Registry` in the Bootstrap
4. Changed `View` references like `$this->siteNav` to `Zend_Registry::get('nav')->getSiteNav()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy Load all the way dude.

- Initializing navigation at boot strap seems like added overhead to the entire application as not every page needs navigation.
- mucking with `Specify routes that don't need the navigation` sounds clugey.

You should extend the Zend Libraries to create your own sorta version library, e.g. extend the core controller. In that extension use that to add a method to build your navigation. In other words subclass your actual application from the extended library classes.

Or create `custom view helpers` to develop your navigation.

Comment: Thanks for outlining the reasons to use lazy-loading.  However, I am still unclear on the specifics for accomplishing lazy-loading.